# is there any default google map marker in android same as in iphone?

Tags: android, google-maps

i am using a google map in my android application.And i want to represent the user's current location default google map marker similar to map marker in iphone.Currently i am using a .png image to represent the current location but need to replace that with a default map marker if it exists in android.

If somebody know then please help me with an example because i have gone through so many examples but none helps me implementing default map marker.                                                                                                                       i have gone through MyLOcationOverlay class also but it didn't help me out.    Please help me ......

Answer (score 6):

Much of the Google map markers can be downloaded legally from the stock online and used. Here are some links

- Here is one source: [Google Earth Icons list](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/geicons.htm)
- Here is another : [Google Maps Icons](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/)

You can use these code bases as examples.

- [IncidentMap](https://github.com/ushahidi/Ushahidi_Android/blob/40652a2af85b08aea2ce33c8337168b84344dfb2/src/org/addhen/ushahidi/IncidentMap.java)
- [MapView Baloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/blob/715d6252ce67382e43e86dfdf656e5cbdbd04165/android-mapviewballoons-example/src/mapviewballoons/example/MyMap.java)

Comment: i do not want an image to be used...the marker should be default

Comment: I don't think that Google provides these "default" markers you speak of.

Comment: please confirm that there is no default google map marker in android

Comment: Yes. The closest you can get to the google maps icons on the android phone is from the Google Maps apk. But remember that reverse engineering that is considered illegal.

Answer (score 0):

use enableMyLocation() in MyLocationOverlay class:

```
mMyLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapView); 
mMyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation(); 
mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
```